# Change chapter format of amsbook

Tags: sectioning, chapters, amsbook

I am trying to change the chapter heading format of an amsbook type document from this:
[image]

to look something like this

[image]

In particular, I would like to change CHAPTER 1 to Chapter 1, make it larger and align it on the left-hand side.

I tried adjusting @makechapterhead. But I only managed to turn CHAPTER 1 into Chapter 1 without changing size or alignment. Any ideas?

Comment: Your text says "align on the right hand side", but the example shows it aligned on the left.  Which do you really want?

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change should be close to what you want.  You will probably want to adjust the `\vspace` values, but that should be straightforward.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\global\topskip 2.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \huge\bfseries                                                                
  \chaptername\enspace\thechapter\par                                           
  \vspace{1pc}                                                                  
     #1\par \endgroup                                                           
  \vspace{2pc}                                                                  
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks Barbara